# Superposition of Poisson Processes with a weighted sum

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-chains, poisson-process

If L(t) and M(t) are independent Poisson Processes, for which a and b is N(t) = a*L(t) + b*M(t) a Poisson Process.
A necessary condition for it to be Poisson is if N(t) has Poisson distribution and a necessary condition for it to be distributed as such is that its mean = variance, so
aλ + bμ = a^2λ + b^2μ and we need a and b positive integers for N(t) to be a counting process so we must have a = b = 1.
Is this correct ?

Comment: How does this imply $a=b=1$?